# How to get name of variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to get name of variable in console.log

```
code1 = 3;
code2 = 1;
code3 = 2;

console.log(Math.min(code1, code2, code3))
```

result is 1 but want also to print in console.log as :
code2 =1

Comment: You probably want to use an object...

Comment: Do you just want this for debugging or something else?

Comment: It's never going to print code2. It's going to print the return value of Math.min().

Comment: Hard to understand how you expect your code to do that...

Answer (score 1):

```
const codeValues = {
  code1: 3,
  code2: 1,
  code3: 2,
};

const minValue = Math.min(codeValues.code1, codeValues.code2, codeValues.code3);
const minCodeName = Object.keys(codeValues).find(key => codeValues[key] === minValue);

console.log(`${minCodeName} = ${minValue}`);
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Comment: so, how to insert variables inside codeValues?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker  That is another question...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss is there any example?

Comment: Depends on what you mean but that - a question with what you tried and expected output would suffice

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
const nums=[3,1,2]

const minIndex= nums.indexOf(Math.min(...nums)),
    codeName= `code${minIndex+1}`

console.log(`${codeName} = ${nums[minIndex]}`)
```

Comment: all your efforts are appreciated :)